# Color Temperature, Contrast, Brightness, and Saturation

Tags: software, video

How Can we measure each of these Parameters for 2 videos ? and the reason behind it is to make a comparison ?

Comment: Is it acceptable to split the video into frames and then compute these values for each? As a programmer, I would say that's totally doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most prosumer-level (or higher) video editing software has monitor panels which show you information about color distribution, luminace, levels and the likes. Premiere Pro for example offers a [range of reference monitors](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/using-waveform-monitors-vectorscope.html#yc_waveform).

Contrary to photo editing, you can't get one measurement of those parameters for the entire video, because they of course vary from frame to frame (I guess you could calculate the average values, but that would be utterly useless). So you can't really compare two videos numerically accurate in that manner.

Comment: I can imagine a theoretical solution would be to analyse every frame of a video using these monitors, to come up with an 'overall' graph, but I've no guesses how to accomplish that.

Comment: But then again, what would that achieve? I mean with a photo you can use it to correct it, but with a video theres no way around looking at individual scenes and frames ...